# haskell list of primes construction; ambiguos type variable

Tags: haskell, ambiguous

I'm trying to make function `primes` which is a list of prime numbers, but somehow I have failed. The compiler throws an error I don't know how to resolve:

**Error:**

`Ambiguous type variable 'a0'`

**Code:**

```
candidates :: [Integer]
candidates = [2]++[3,5..]

primes :: [Integer]
primes = filter is_prime candidates

is_prime :: Integer -> Bool
is_prime candidate
    | candidate == 1 = False
    | candidate == 2 = True
    | candidate == 3 = True
    | otherwise = r_is_prime candidate 0

-- r as recursive
r_is_prime :: Integer -> Integer -> Bool
r_is_prime candidate order
    | n_th_prime >= max_compared_prime = True
    | candidate `mod` n_th_prime  == 0 = False
    | otherwise = if (r_is_prime candidate (order+1) ) then True else False
    where 
        n_th_prime = candidates !! fromIntegral(order)
        -- this is the line that throws an error...
        max_compared_prime = fromIntegral ( ceiling ( fromIntegral ( sqrt ( fromIntegral candidate))))
```

Comment: `primes = 2 : 3 : [n | n<-[5,7..], foldr (\p r-> p*p>n || (rem n p /= 0 && r)) True (tail primes)]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In

```
max_compared_prime = fromIntegral ( ceiling ( fromIntegral ( sqrt ( fromIntegral candidate))))
```

you have a `fromIntegral` too much. `sqrt` has type

```
sqrt :: Floating a => a -> a
```

so the result of `sqrt` is not a member of an `Integral` type. And the result of `ceiling` is an `Integral` type, so the last `fromIntegral` is superfluous (but does not harm).

```
max_compared_prime = ceiling ( sqrt ( fromIntegral candidate))
```

is all you need in that line.

Note, however, that

```
n_th_prime = candidates !! fromIntegral(order)
```

means that to test against the `n`-th candidate prime, the list of candidates has to be traversed until the `n`-th prime has been reached. Thus testing against the `n`-th candidate is O(n) here instead of O(1) [Well, assuming that numbers are bounded] which a single division is.

A more efficient trial division only tries primes for the division and remembers where in the list of primes it was when it goes on to the next prime. For example

```
is_prime :: Integer -> Bool
is_prime n
    | n < 2     = False
    | n < 4     = True
    | otherwise = trialDivision primes
      where
        r = floor (sqrt $ fromIntegral n)
        trialDivision (p:ps)
            | r < p     = True
            | otherwise = n `rem` p /= 0 && trialDivision ps
```

Just traverses the list of primes in order to do the trial division, hence going from one prime to the next is a simple step in the list.

Comment: how can I test against n-th prime in O(1) ?

Comment: By remembering where you were in the list of primes. I'll edit a more efficient implementation of `is_prime` in.

Comment: I don't know where is the problem but your version of is_prime doesn't return any answer... (tried "primes !! 5" and it didn't return anything....)

Comment: Ah, because `ceiling (sqrt 5)` is 3. Fixed now, `floor` instead of `ceiling`.

Comment: That's odd. It works here. In which way exactly doesn't it work for you? - Except, I accidentally edited the wrong 'ceiling' in my answer previously, oops.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10646/discussion-between-tomy-and-daniel-fischer)

Answer (score 3):

You have too many `fromIntegral`s in

```
max_compared_prime = fromIntegral ( ceiling ( fromIntegral ( sqrt ( fromIntegral candidate))))
```

The `fromIntegral` applied to the result of `sqrt` is causing the error. If we look at the type signatures, we have:

```
fromIntegral :: (Num b, Integral a) => a -> b
sqrt :: Floating a => a -> a
```

So to properly infer the type of `fromIntegral (sqrt x)` Haskell needs to find a type with both `Floating` and `Integral` instances (so that the result of `sqrt` matches the parameter of `fromIntegral`). Haskell can't find such a type and so (basically) is asking you to specify one (but there isn't one). The solution is to just elide this `fromIntegral`:

```
max_compared_prime = fromIntegral ( ceiling ( sqrt ( fromIntegral candidate)))
```

#### other notes

Brackets aren't particularly idiomatic Haskell, so that line can/should be written as:

```
max_compared_prime = fromIntegral . ceiling . sqrt . fromIntegral $ candidate
```

Furthermore, the result of `ceiling` doesn't need to be converted, so it can even be:

```
max_compared_prime = ceiling . sqrt . fromIntegral $ candidate
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove 'fromIntegral' from before 'sqrt', as:

```
max_compared_prime = fromIntegral ( ceiling ( sqrt ( fromIntegral candidate)))
```

The types are:

```
sqrt :: Floating a => a -> a
fromIntegral :: (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b
```

the output of sqrt is 'Floating', not Integral.